# JavaFX Pop Up window throws exception when called again

Tags: java, exception, javafx, error-handling

I am currently trying to write a simple application in Java using JavaFX.

In the application I want to have a pop up window that prompts the user for input. This works fine, as long as the user doesn't try to open the pop up window again.
If he does that the following error occurs:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Grid hgap=5.0, vgap=0.0, alignment=TOP_LEFTis already set as root of another scene
```

And here is the code that opens the window:

In the main view controller:

```
btAddChat.setOnAction(e -> lvItems.add(PopUpVC.display()));
```

And in the view controller for the pop up:

```
public class PopUpVC
{
    private static final GridPane root = new GridPane();
    private static final TextField tfInput = new TextField();
    private static final Button btOK = new Button("OK");
    private static String result;
    private static Stage primaryStage = new Stage();


public static String display()
{
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 50);
    MainVC mvc = new MainVC();
    root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

    root.setHgap(5);

    tfInput.setPrefWidth(scene.getWidth()*0.65);

    root.add(btOK, 0, 0, 1, 1);
    root.add(tfInput, 1, 0, 1, 1);

    btOK.setOnAction(e ->
    {
        if(!tfInput.getText().equals(""))
        {
            primaryStage.close();
        }
    });

    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.showAndWait();
    return tfInput.getText();
}
```

I only copied the most important part, the actual error is a lot longer. I know what is causing the error (trying to open a window with the same root throws an error because the root is already in use), I just can't figure out how to resolve it.

Here is a picture of the application:

[image: The top left button opens the pop up]

The top left button opens the pop up.

The pop up:

[image: The pop up]

If there are any suggestions on how to resolve this issue I would be very glad to hear them, if there should be any another way to open a pop up window that prompts the user for text input, I would also be glad to hear about those!

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: The error message is pretty self-explanatory: the `GridPane` is already the root of one scene, and you try to make it the root of another scene. It's almost always a mistake (or at least bad design) to make everything `static`, but either way the `GridPane` should be the root of a single scene.

Comment: I figured it out, easy thing really, I added a parameter to the start function so when I call it I just give it a new GridPane() and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Also consider using a [`TextInputDialog`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TextInputDialog.html)

Comment: @James_D Thank you for your comment, when would it be a good idea to make something static, I am still learning and am happy to get some advice!

Comment: *"when would it be a good idea to make something static*". Almost never... There are some good use cases for `static` methods in factory patterns, but in anything but fairly advanced coding styles the only things that should be static are constants and the `main()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP's solution:

> I figured it out, easy thing really, I added a parameter to the start function so when I call it I just give it a new GridPane() and it works perfectly fine.

Is really the wrong approach.  As @James_D pointed out, `static` is not a good idea for anything like this.  Trying to keep with the original design as much as possible, I'd suggest this, which builds the PopUp just once, and re-displays it:

```
public class PopUp extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button button = new Button("Click Me");
        PopUpVC popUpVC = new PopUpVC();
        button.setOnAction(evt -> {
            popUpVC.display();
        });
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(button));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public class PopUpVC {
        private final TextField tfInput = new TextField();
        private Stage primaryStage = new Stage();


        public PopUpVC() {
            GridPane root = new GridPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 50);
            root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
            root.setHgap(5);
            tfInput.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty().multiply(0.65));
            Button btOK = new Button("OK");
            root.add(btOK, 0, 0, 1, 1);
            root.add(tfInput, 1, 0, 1, 1);
            btOK.setOnAction(e -> {
                if (!tfInput.getText().equals("")) {
                    primaryStage.close();
                }
            });
            primaryStage.setResizable(false);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        }

        public String display() {
            primaryStage.showAndWait();
            return tfInput.getText();
        }
    }
}
```

When you have something that's completely static, like `PopUpVC`, that's a hint that it's just code that you've moved out of somewhere else.  This is useful, and a good practice, if you are calling the methods from a variety of other classes, when it saves code duplication.  However, you shouldn't have JavaFX elements as static fields in such a class.

In this case, you can do away with `PopUpVC` and move all of the code into a local method:

```
public class PopUp extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button button = new Button("Click Me");
        button.setOnAction(evt -> {
            displayPopUpVC();
        });
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(button));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public String displayPopUpVC() {
        TextField tfInput = new TextField();
        Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 50);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.setHgap(5);
        tfInput.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty().multiply(0.65));
        Button btOK = new Button("OK");
        root.add(btOK, 0, 0, 1, 1);
        root.add(tfInput, 1, 0, 1, 1);
        btOK.setOnAction(e -> {
            if (!tfInput.getText().equals("")) {
                primaryStage.close();
            }
        });
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.showAndWait();
        return tfInput.getText();
    }
}
```

This behaves slightly different from the first solution because it doesn't retain the text in the TextField between calls.  But the default text could be passed in a parameter if you wanted.

But, also as @James_D has pointed out, `TextInputDialog` does exactly what you want.  Plus it does it with about 4 lines of code:

```
public class PopUp extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button button = new Button("Click Me");
        TextInputDialog dialog = new TextInputDialog();
        dialog.setHeaderText(null);
        dialog.setTitle("Chat");
        dialog.setGraphic(null);
        button.setOnAction(evt -> {
            dialog.showAndWait();
        });
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(button));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for putting this much work into the answer, this really helped me out! Would it be ok for you if I used this in my homework? If not that's fine I'd just take a bit of inspiration from your approach.

Comment: Use it as you like, as long as you learn something.